# Running AngularJS app in WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

Its been about a month since I started using AngularJS. I used to write my codes in SublimeText2 but i wanted to use WebStorm since it claimed to be more AngularJS friendly. I wrote a simple Hello World app and tried to run it but i couldn't get any hint of how to do it. I also don't have any knowledge about Node.js.

- Do i need Node.js to run app on WebStorm?

  Is Node.js a server?

I tried going through tutorials on WebStorm page and also read few articles on Node.js but couldn't understand it. Can anyone explain it in a simple and understandable way?

Comment: WebStorm could be used for purely html+JavaScript front end development.  However it has good support of node.js development. If you use node.js on back end, you could get benefits from using WebStorm on both front end and back end.

Comment: @AndreiBeziazychnyi suppose i write a Hello World app using just HTML and JavaScript in WebStorm, then how do i run that HTML? In SublimeText or any other editor, i write my codes on editor and then execute that particular HTML file from where it is located in the directory, is it same process with WebStorm? What is "run" in WebStorm for? I am very confused with that run function.

Comment: WebStorm goes with its own internal web server. Let's assume you have project named MyApp and index.html in the root. You could use the following url then http://localhost:63342/MyApp/index.html. You don't need run configuration in this case.

Comment: Thank you @AndreiBeziazychnyi. Even though i am not satisfied completely i really do appreciate your help. thank you for taking time to answer :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can open your HTML+JS application in the selected browser in WebStorm by clicking on the browser icon on the top right corner of the editor tab with index.html file opened (or any other html file you'd like to open in browser).
[image]

The same action could be done from the file context menu: Open in - Browser.
WebStorm will automatically start built-in web server for your convenience.

Note that you still can go to your project folder and execute your particular HTML file from there, the same way you would do it with the text editor.

Read more on working with AngularJS in WebStorm in this [blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/).

If you have back-end in Node.js for your app, then you, of course, need Node.js installed. To run your node web app you need to create Node.js run configuration. More on it [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/02/running-and-debugging-node-js-application/).